# Alert after checkout with woocommerce from function.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using woocommerce to take appointement, I know it kind a weird but it's perfect for this project.

After the checkout, I redirect the user to the home page and I want to display an alert or a bar to say "Message send successfully"

How can I manage that from function.php ?

Code from my function.php :

```php
function woocommerce_redirect_after_checkout() {
global $wp;

if ( is_checkout() && ! empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    
    wp_redirect(get_home_url() );
    
    //HERE echo '<script>alert('bla')</script>';

exit;
}

}
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two hooks.

for redirect to home page use `template_redirect` WC action hook.

> Use `add_query_arg` function to add message args. that you can use
> later on the home page.

```
function redirect_to_home_page_with_message() {
    global $wp;
    if ( is_checkout() && ! empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
        wp_safe_redirect( add_query_arg( array( 'message' => 'Message send successfully' ), get_home_url() ) );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_home_page_with_message' );
```

for displaying a success message using WP `wp_footer` action hook.

```
function show_success_message(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php if( isset( $_GET['message'] ) && $_GET['message'] != '' ){ ?>
            alert('<?php echo $_GET['message']; ?>');
        <?php } ?>
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'show_success_message', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Yes a lot, (sorry for the wait) The problem is on the checkout page the order button is stuck in a loading and when I take off the show_success_messgae function everything work good. Any idea ?

Comment: The function show_success_messgae() function mess with my footer and block the checkout. You know why ?

Comment: I don't this it's related to my function.

Comment: Perfect, Thx mate